# JQuery copy textarea value into a div for printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing, textarea

I'm trying to set up print styles for textareas on a very long form. The client needs to be able to print the page (from any browser) with all of the text shown from each textarea. I haven't found any way to do this with pure CSS (I've tried overflow:visible and height:auto/100% attributes and neither work) so I am wondering how I can accomplish this with jquery.

FYI, there will be no on click function or anything. I have the textarea displaying for screen and a hidden div below it. For print, I am hiding the textarea and showing the "forprint" div. So I need the value for the printed div to always match the value of the textarea.

```
<div class="forscreen">@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.Subtitle, AdminOnlyAttribute(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "k-textbox" }, { "rows", "6" } }))</div>
<div class="forprint"></div>


.forprint {
    display: none;
}

@media print {
    .forprint {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }

    .forscreen {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Naturally, I figured it out shortly after I posted the question. Here is the jquery that did it:

```
$('div textarea').focus(function () {
        var copyText = $(this).val();
        $(".forprint").html(copyText);
    });
```

Now, I am wondering is there a way that I can do this for all textareas on the page without creating unique ID's and functions for each of them?

Comment: Do you have any javascript that copies the textarea content to the div as it's entered? or are you hoping we'll write that part.

Comment: Just to clarify, the div will be hidden to the regular browser generally, but once the client clicks print, then the text inside the textarea should be visible through the hidden div ? If that correct, your css is fine. Just use jquery 'attr' tool to extract the text from the text area and put it inside the hidden div. Once the user clicks print, the media print css should activate the div with the text.

Comment: you might want to do that on blur or change instead, focus won't catch updates after the focus happens.

Comment: Ah okay cool. Thanks for help. Any ideas on my last question? I'm not a JS expert or anything so I'm just wondering what the best way to go about it would be.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle to get what you're really doing but to get the text from all textareas once a user clicks on the print button, based on my little knowledge, the window.document object loses focus - blur event. With focus on that event to trigger the text copying, I think the following would do:

```
$(document).blur(function(e)
{
   var textObj = $("textarea").toArray();
   for(var i = 0; i<textObj.length; ++i)
   {
       var mytext = textObj[i].val();
       $(".forprint").append(mytext);
   }
}
```

You may also want to try with the blur event of the body element. I hope that works. Regards and all the best